# How can I set Unity to dependency inject repositories to my service layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container

I have set up a bootstrapper as follows:

```
    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IService<Account>, AccountService>();
        container.RegisterControllers();           
        return container;
    }
```

My controller looks like this:

```
    public AccountsController(IService<Account> accountService) {
        _account = accountService;
    }
```

When called it correctly sets up _account from the accountService which looks like this:

```
public class AccountService : BaseService, IService<Account>
{
    public AccountService() { base.Initialize();
        _accountRepository = StorageHelper.GetTable<Account>();
        _productRepository = StorageHelper.GetTable<Product>(); 
}
```

You can see here that the AccountService depends on setting up two repositories.  In Unity is there some way that I can also specify this dependence so I don't have to code in StorageHelper.GetTable();

**Update:**

I added the following code after suggestion below:

```
 public AccountService(
            IAzureTable<Account> accountRepository, 
            IAzureTable<Product> productRepository) { 
            //base.Initialize(); 
            _accountRepository = accountRepository; 
            _productRepository = productRepository;  
        }
```

Here's the original code:

```
   public static IAzureTable<T> GetTable<T>() where T : TableServiceEntity
    {
        return new AzureTable<T>(GetStorageAccount(), TableNames[typeof(T)]);
    }
```

Then tried to set up these types in the bootstrapper as follows:

```
 container.RegisterType<IAzureTable<Account>, AzureTable<Account>(GetStorageAccount(), "TestAccounts")>();
 container.RegisterType<IAzureTable<Product>, AzureTable<Product>(GetStorageAccount(), "TestProducts")>();
```

I guess there's something I don't understand as this produced a lot of syntax errors. Am I doing it wrong here?

Comment: What syntax errors are you getting, for example?

Comment: On the line:  container.RegisterType<IAzureTable<Account>    Error 14 Invalid expression term ','   There are ten syntax errors for those two lines starting with container. Syntax errors pointing to the , saying ; is needed saying ) is needed.

Comment: You should wrap the IAzureTable<Account> in a TypeOf() statement, that should help :) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660936(v=PandP.20).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, treat those two repositories as constructor arguments and Unity will wire them up for your as specified in your bootstrapper:

```
public class AccountService : BaseService, IService<Account> 
{ 
    public AccountService(StorageHelperType accountRepo, StorageHelperType productRepo) { base.Initialize(); 
        _accountRepository = accountRepo; 
        _productRepository = productRepo;  
}
```

In your bootstrapper you should be able to specify where exactly it will get those arguments from using the InjectionConstructor (a good example [here](http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2008/10/28/specifying-injection-constructor-using-unity-fluent-interface-for-loose-coupling-and-poco/)) (assuming they are different types, if they are different types you can just wire them up and Unity will sort them out).

### Edit for new info

When you register your generic types with Unity, wrap them in a TypeOf statement, since that seems to be how you get around generics with Unity (source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660936%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx))

Comment: I updated my question but something is still wrong in the bootstrapper. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I use Castle Windsor in my MVC3 application for dependency injection, but I think Unity works roughly the same. I based my dependency injection based on [this blog post](http://kenneththorman.blogspot.com/2011/03/aspnet-mvc-3-dependency-injection-using.html). You can see he creates his own `WindsorControllerFactory`instead of using the default controller factory, which automatically injects the dependencies.

After some googling, I did find some blog posts about using Unity in MVC3, like [this [1]](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/02/08/how-to-use-unity-container-in-asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx), [this[2]](http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/UnityIoCASPNETMVCFrameworkDependencyInjectionControllers.aspx) and [this[3]](https://dotnetslang.wordpress.com/2011/03/12/how-to-create-a-unity-controller-factory-2/), and they all seem to be creating a `UnityControllerFactory` too. So I think that's what you need to do to have automatic constructor injection.